# Read text file from server and split into multiple file in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

read text file from the server and split into mutiple file in asp.net
for example one text file is located in server which size as 2 mb.
i want to divide this text file into five text file and write into the folder.

Comment: i have solution for the above question but it take lot time to do file split process.

Comment: Provide the code you already have.

Comment: It's doable! I think you have to start with **the learning of asp.net** itself, it's basic work with files and directories. When you'll be done with it, please, read [the following section](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before asking the next question.

Comment: i know its basic of asp.net. i have question is that ,i done on my site its take lot time to do the spliting the file .....if any another way to do ......

Answer (score 0):

public void SplitFile(string Filename, int Parts)
    {

```
    string str=File.ReadAllText(Filename);
    str = str.Replace("\r\n", "");
    int totalScore=str.Length;
    int div = totalScore / Parts; 
    int mod = totalScore % Parts;
    string result="";
    for (int i = 1; i <= Parts; i++)
    {
        if (i == Parts)
        {
            div = div+mod;
        }
        result = str.Substring(0, div);
        str = str.Remove(0, div);
        System.IO.File.WriteAllText(Filename.Replace(".", i +"."), result);
    }

}
```